# Parse.com: set Date as datatype with null value

Tags: javascript, date, parse-platform

i've read https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-types and try to set:

```
if (ColumNames[j]=="tanggal_lahir" || ColumNames[j]=="trxdate") {
                                    debugger;
                                    if (objectData[j]="") {
                                        table_object.set(ColumNames[j],null);
                                    } else { 
                                        table_object.set(ColumNames[j], new Date(objectData[j]));
                                    }
                                }
```

But why still got error?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be setting the value of objectData[j] to an empty string instead of comparing it e.g *if (objectData[j]="")* what you need to do is... **if (objectData[j]=="")**
because the if operator returns a Boolean value either true or false, so it needs sometime to compare to, and you are assigning a value in the if logic.

Comment: Thanks... my all data as String. most of them have value. But there are several data just emptyString. so i used to set for nulled data. All of my data that have value for this column ("tanggal_lahir) setted well at parse. but not for null or undefined data.

Answer (score 0):

Alhamdulillah i've fixed my problem.. to fix it... just don't set any thing if they have null value.

so if my code it should be-->  Move if (objectData[j] =="") { to first line:

```
if (objectData[j] !="") {
         if (ColumNames[j]=="tanggal_lahir" || ColumNames[j]=="trxdate") {
                table_object.set(ColumNames[j], new Date(objectData[j]));
         } else {
                table_object.set(ColumNames[j], objectData[j]);
         }
}
```